# (WPF) Does .Close() method releases the window instance?

Tags: wpf, navigation, window

I'm creating a new window in On_Click method. First I tried this;

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CustomerOperations customerOperationsWindow;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        customerOperationsWindow = new CustomerOperations();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        customerOperationsWindow.Owner = this;
        customerOperationsWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

It's not working so I started creating the window instance every time the user clicks on the Customers button. And I used the following codes.

```
 private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerOperations customerOperationsWindow = new CustomerOperations();
        customerOperationsWindow.Owner = this;
        customerOperationsWindow.Show();
    }
```

In the new window, If user clicks to Main button, I want to navigate to main window.

```
private void btnMain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        this.Owner.Show();
    }
```

First question: Does this.Close() releases the window instance?

Second question: Is this usage correct?

What do you think is the best practice?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window.Close()` will dispose all resources allocated by the instance. That's why you cannot show it again once it was closed.

If you want to reuse the same `Window` instance, you should cancel the closing procedure to prevent disposal of internal resources and collapse the Window instead (by setting `Window.Visibility` to `Visibility.Collapsed` - `Visibility.Collapsed` is also the default value of an instantiated `Window` before `Window.Show()` is called).

Alternatively hide the `Window` by calling `Window.Hide()` (which will set the `Visibility` to `Visibility.Hidden`) instead of `Window.Close()`.

Calling `Window.Show` will also set the window's visibility to `Visibility.Visible`.
As a matter of fact, showing a `Window` by setting `Window.Visibility` is the asynchronous version of `Window.Show()`.

Generally, you switch between Window instances by using the [`Window.Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.activate?view=net-5.0) method. Calling `Window.Show` on a `Window` that is currently showing/visible, does nothing.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CustomerOperations CustomerOperationsWindow { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CustomerOperationsWindow = new CustomerOperations();

        // Consider to move this logic to CustomerOperations class,
        // where you can override the OnClosing method instead of subscribing to the event
        this.CustomerOperationsWindow.Closing += CollapseWindow_OnClosing;
    }

    // Cancel close  to prevent disposal and collapse Window instead
    private void CollapseWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Cancel = true;
      this.CustomerOperationsWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      this.CustomerOperationsWindow.Owner.Activate();
    }

    private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CustomerOperationsWindow.Owner = this;

        // Calling Show will set the Visibility to Visibility.Visible
        this.CustomerOperationsWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Creating a Window instance allocates unmanaged resources. If this happens very frequently, you will keep the garbage collector busy. From a performance point of view you may want to avoid it and prefer to reuse the same instance.
In a common scenario this is not necessary. But since `Window` exposes a `Hide()` method, you may consider to use it instead of `Close()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to the parent window, you can use the code `this.Owner.Activate();` and if you want to close the current window, first `this.Owner.Activate();` and then  `this.Close();`.

When you enter `this.Close()`, the compiler does not execute the following lines after reaching it. And when a sample window still exists there is no need to recreate it

```
private void btnMain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.Activate();
    this.Close();
}
```